# Everytime i build my .netcore project, the DLL file will be always generated even if i have no any changes on code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

like below, i created an example project:

1>------ Build started: Project: WebApplication5, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>WebApplication5 -> C:\Users\Rain\source\repos\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\WebApplication5.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

i have no any changes to the project, but when build the project, it always output a new DLL file,

is it common?

Comment: from my understanding, if there's no code changes, then VS don't need to compile anything,  i have another C++ project in same solution, and if no changes it will not compile anything when i click build.  i don't know if DLL or .net core is special?

Answer (score 0):

Select the modified files only in Visual Studio, right-mouse click and compile it. It compiles only modified files and then build it. Do not REBUILD it.

It takes less time compared to simply building the whole project. Not sure about new versions of VS.net IDE.

Comment: Hey, thanks. actually we put everything in a builder, if there's any changes the whole solution will start build but not RE-BUILDING.  so basically it should only take the changes and compile that we need, so now only the .netcore project is special, it always re-build the DLL even if there's no any changes.

Comment: Sounds like your "builder" is set to recompile and replace ALL objects

Comment: we use /build for the project, from my understanding if there's no changes then the builder shouldn't re-build it, do you know that where can i check about this part of settings?

Comment: A build builds if anything has changed. Maybe there is a pre build script or your assembly version is set to something like 1.*.* or you have a T4 file in your code or a resource file that detects an included file has changed. You could call the build command in verbose mode to better find the root cause.